# change tray icon based on event

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have code that will start process in tray (task bar). After right click on tray icon it will show menu. After clicking on first menu item winform window starts. This winform shows status about the notepad process. My goal is to change the tray icon based on the status of notepad (if notepad is running then show `online.ico` otherwise show `offline.ico`). If I understand correct then my code is starting/stopping `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` every time winform window is opened/closed and I'm not sure if this is the best possible approach. My guess is that I need to somehow start timer "outside" of `OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn` so it can somehow reload `*.ico` files. Following script is heavily inspired by [this](http://www.systanddeploy.com/2018/12/create-your-own-powershell.html) site:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

function Test-Notepad {
    [bool](Get-Process -Name 'notepad' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
}


function OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn () {
    # Build Label object
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $Label.Name = "labelName"
        $Label.AutoSize = $True

    # Set and start timer
    $timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    $timer.Interval = 1000
    $timer.Add_Tick({
        if ($Label){
            $Label.Text = if (Test-Notepad) { "Notepad is running" } else { "Notepad is NOT running" }
        }
    })
    $timer.Start()


    # Build Form object
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form.Text = "My Form"
        $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
        $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
        $Form.Topmost = $True
        $Form.Add_Closing({ $timer.Dispose() })  # Dispose() also stops the timer.
        $Form.Controls.Add($Label)               # Add label to form
        $form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null             # Show the Form
}


function OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn () {
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $false
    $window.Close()
    Stop-Process $pid
}


function create_taskbar_menu{
    # Create menu items
    $Main_Tool_Icon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Text = "Icon Text"
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = $icon
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $true

    $MenuItem1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem1.Text = "Menu Item 1"

    $MenuItem2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem2.Text = "Menu Item 2"

    $MenuItem3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem3.Text = "Menu Item 3"

    $MenuItem4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem4.Text = "Exit"


    # Add menu items to context menu
    $contextmenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
    $Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu = $contextmenu
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem1)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem2)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem3)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem4)


    $MenuItem4.add_Click({OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn})
    $MenuItem1.add_Click({OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn})
}


$Current_Folder = split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# Add assemblies for WPF and Mahapps
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')    | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')   | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')          | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('WindowsFormsIntegration') | out-null
# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Current_Folder\assembly\MahApps.Metro.dll")  | out-null

# Choose an icon to display in the systray
$icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/online.ico")
# use this icon when notepad is not running
# $icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/offline.ico")


create_taskbar_menu

# Make PowerShell Disappear - Thanks Chrissy
$windowcode = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
$asyncwindow = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $windowcode -name Win32ShowWindowAsync -namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$null = $asyncwindow::ShowWindowAsync((Get-Process -PID $pid).MainWindowHandle, 0)




# Use a Garbage colection to reduce Memory RAM
# https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/freeing-up-memory-in-powershell-using-garbage-collector/
# https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2
[System.GC]::Collect()

# Create an application context for it to all run within - Thanks Chrissy
# This helps with responsiveness, especially when clicking Exit - Thanks Chrissy
$appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
```

**EDITED: working solution based on @BACON answer**

```
# Toggle following two lines
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
# Set-StrictMode -Off

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

function Test-Notepad {
    [bool](Get-Process -Name 'notepad' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
}


function OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn () {
    # Build Form object
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form.Text = "My Form"
        $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
        $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
        $Form.Topmost = $True
        $Form.Controls.Add($Label)               # Add label to form
        $form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null             # Show the Form
}


function OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn () {
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $false

    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit()
}


function create_taskbar_menu{
    # Create menu items
    $MenuItem1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem1.Text = "Menu Item 1"

    $MenuItem2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem2.Text = "Menu Item 2"

    $MenuItem3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem3.Text = "Menu Item 3"

    $MenuItem4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem4.Text = "Exit"


    # Add menu items to context menu
    $contextmenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
    $Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu = $contextmenu
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem1)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem2)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem3)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem4)


    $MenuItem4.add_Click({OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn})
    $MenuItem1.add_Click({OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn})
}


$Current_Folder = split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# Add assemblies for WPF and Mahapps
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')    | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')   | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')          | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('WindowsFormsIntegration') | out-null
# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Current_Folder\assembly\MahApps.Metro.dll")  | out-null

# Choose an icon to display in the systray
$onlineIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/online.ico")
# use this icon when notepad is not running
$offlineIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/offline.ico")

$Main_Tool_Icon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$Main_Tool_Icon.Text = "Icon Text"
$Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = if (Test-Notepad) { $onlineIcon } else { $offlineIcon }
$Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $true

# Build Label object
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label.Name = "labelName"
    $Label.AutoSize = $True

# Initialize the timer
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000
$timer.Add_Tick({
    if ($Label){
        $Label.Text, $Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = if (Test-Notepad) {
            "Notepad is running", $onlineIcon
        } else {
            "Notepad is NOT running", $offlineIcon
        }
    }
})
$timer.Start()

create_taskbar_menu

# Make PowerShell Disappear - Thanks Chrissy
$windowcode = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
$asyncwindow = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $windowcode -name Win32ShowWindowAsync -namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$null = $asyncwindow::ShowWindowAsync((Get-Process -PID $pid).MainWindowHandle, 0)

# Use a Garbage colection to reduce Memory RAM
# https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/freeing-up-memory-in-powershell-using-garbage-collector/
# https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2
[System.GC]::Collect()

# Create an application context for it to all run within - Thanks Chrissy
# This helps with responsiveness, especially when clicking Exit - Thanks Chrissy
$appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
try
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)    
}
finally
{
    foreach ($component in $timer, $Main_Tool_Icon, $offlineIcon, $onlineIcon, $appContext)
    {
        # The following test returns $false if $component is
        # $null, which is really what we're concerned about
        if ($component -is [System.IDisposable])
        {
            $component.Dispose()
        }
    }

    Stop-Process -Id $PID
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Yes, the lifetime of `$timer` coincides with that of `$Form`, however if `$MenuItem1` is invoked multiple times without closing `$Form` then you will have multiple `Timer`s and `Form`s running at the same time.  The [`Register-WmiEvent` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/register-wmievent) would be a way to be notified of `notepad.exe` process creation/destruction without the use of timers and polling.

Comment: @BACON my question is about how to modify above code to change tray icon. And also about if above code is correct in term of calling `$timer.Dispose()` in `$Form.Add_Closing()` thx

Comment: Small remark here. Powershell is not meant to create apps that stay in memory and have tray icons. What you've done is to code a win32 application from C# in powershell. Why not stay in C# and I'm sure you'll find plenty of answers for your tray icon question. Otherwise, if you still need this in PowerShell and you can obviously code C# winforms in Powershell, search for your question in C# forums and do the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have code to set the icon used by the `NotifyIcon`...

```bsh
$Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = $icon
```

...and to define the icons to use...

```bsh
# Choose an icon to display in the systray
$icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/online.ico")
# use this icon when notepad is not running
# $icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/offline.ico")
```

...and to periodically test if `Notepad` is running and respond appropriately...

```bsh
$timer.Add_Tick({
    if ($Label){
        $Label.Text = if (Test-Notepad) { "Notepad is running" } else { "Notepad is NOT running" }
    }
})
```

You just need to combine them with a couple additional tweaks...

- Store each icon in its own variable with a descriptive name so its easy to switch between them.
- `$Main_Tool_Icon` needs to be defined outside the scope of `create_taskbar_menu` so it can be accessed inside of `OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn`.  I moved the creation and initialization to just before the call to `create_taskbar_menu`, but you could also initialize it inside of `create_taskbar_menu` or some other function.

That ends up looking like this...

```bsh
# Choose an icon to display in the systray
$onlineIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/online.ico")
# use this icon when notepad is not running
$offlineIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/offline.ico")

$Main_Tool_Icon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$Main_Tool_Icon.Text = "Icon Text"
$Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = if (Test-Notepad) { $onlineIcon } else { $offlineIcon }
$Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $true

create_taskbar_menu
```

...and this...

```bsh
$timer.Add_Tick({
    if ($Label){
        # Change the text and icon with one test
        $Label.Text, $Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = if (Test-Notepad) {
            "Notepad is running", $onlineIcon
        } else {
            "Notepad is NOT running", $offlineIcon
        }
    }
})
```

You'll see that an icon is selected based on the result of `Test-Notepad` both when `$Main_Tool_Icon` is initialized and when the `Tick` event is raised.

As for disposing `$timer` when `$Form` is closing...

```bsh
$Form.Add_Closing({ $timer.Dispose() })
```

...that is *almost* an appropriate place to do that, however...

- The [`Closing` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing) is raised essentially when the form has been *requested* to close; it provides an opportunity for that request to be canceled.  The [`Closed` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closed) would be more appropriate because it is raised when the form has actually been closed.
- The documentation states that both the `Closing` and `Closed` events are obsolete.  Use the [`FormClosed` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed) instead.

Also, in `OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn` you are calling `$window.Close()` even though `$window` is not defined; I think you meant `$Form.Close()`.  An alternative that I think is a bit cleaner would be to have clicking the `Exit` menu item merely [exit the Windows Forms application loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit)...

```bsh
function OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn () {
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $false

    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit()
}
```

...and then you can put your cleanup/teardown code in a `finally` block at the end of the script...

```bsh
try
{
    # This call returns when [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit() is called
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
}
finally
{
    # $timer would also have to be defined at the script scope
    # (outside of OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn) for this to work
    $timer.Dispose()

    # $Form, $Label, $Main_Tool_Icon, $onlineIcon, etc. would all be candidates for disposal...

    # Exit the entire PowerShell process
    Stop-Process $pid
}
```

---

The following is complete code that incorporates the changes mentioned above and works for me...

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

function Test-Notepad {
    [bool](Get-Process -Name 'notepad' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
}


function OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn () {
    $timer.Start()

    # Build Form object
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form.Text = "My Form"
        $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
        $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
        $Form.Topmost = $True
        $Form.Add_Closing({ $timer.Dispose() })  # Dispose() also stops the timer.
        $Form.Controls.Add($Label)               # Add label to form
        $form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null             # Show the Form
}


function OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn () {
    $Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $false

    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit()
}


function create_taskbar_menu{
    # Create menu items
    $MenuItem1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem1.Text = "Menu Item 1"

    $MenuItem2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem2.Text = "Menu Item 2"

    $MenuItem3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem3.Text = "Menu Item 3"

    $MenuItem4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $MenuItem4.Text = "Exit"


    # Add menu items to context menu
    $contextmenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
    $Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu = $contextmenu
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem1)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem2)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem3)
    $Main_Tool_Icon.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($MenuItem4)


    $MenuItem4.add_Click({OnMenuItem4ClickEventFn})
    $MenuItem1.add_Click({OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn})
}


$Current_Folder = split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# Add assemblies for WPF and Mahapps
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')    | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')   | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')          | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('WindowsFormsIntegration') | out-null
# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Current_Folder\assembly\MahApps.Metro.dll")  | out-null

# Choose an icon to display in the systray
$onlineIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/online.ico")
# use this icon when notepad is not running
$offlineIcon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Current_Folder/icons/offline.ico")

$Main_Tool_Icon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$Main_Tool_Icon.Text = "Icon Text"
$Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = if (Test-Notepad) { $onlineIcon } else { $offlineIcon }
$Main_Tool_Icon.Visible = $true

# Build Label object
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label.Name = "labelName"
    $Label.AutoSize = $True

# Initialize the timer
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000
$timer.Add_Tick({
    if ($Label){
        $Label.Text, $Main_Tool_Icon.Icon = if (Test-Notepad) {
            "Notepad is running", $onlineIcon
        } else {
            "Notepad is NOT running", $offlineIcon
        }
    }
})

create_taskbar_menu

# Make PowerShell Disappear - Thanks Chrissy
$windowcode = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
$asyncwindow = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $windowcode -name Win32ShowWindowAsync -namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$null = $asyncwindow::ShowWindowAsync((Get-Process -PID $pid).MainWindowHandle, 0)

# Use a Garbage colection to reduce Memory RAM
# https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/freeing-up-memory-in-powershell-using-garbage-collector/
# https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2
[System.GC]::Collect()

# Create an application context for it to all run within - Thanks Chrissy
# This helps with responsiveness, especially when clicking Exit - Thanks Chrissy
$appContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
try
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)    
}
finally
{
    foreach ($component in $timer, $form, $Main_Tool_Icon, $offlineIcon, $onlineIcon, $appContext)
    {
        # The following test returns $false if $component is
        # $null, which is really what we're concerned about
        if ($component -is [System.IDisposable])
        {
            $component.Dispose()
        }
    }

    Stop-Process -Id $PID
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply and sorry for later response. I've modified original question.

Comment: As I say in my answer, you need to define `$Main_Tool_Icon` outside of `create_taskbar_menu` so it is visible inside of `OnMenuItem1ClickEventFn`.  You are still defining it inside of `create_taskbar_menu`, so when the `Tick` event handler tries to set the `Icon` property `$Main_Tool_Icon` should `$null` since it's out of scope.  (Alternatively, you could replace all references with `$script:Main_Tool_Icon` to explicitly define the variable at the `script` scope.)

Comment: @WakanTanka I have updated my answer with the complete code that works for me.

Comment: I've recently discovered that tray icon is changed only after I click on `MenuItem1` so I've moved `$timer.Start()` after `$timer.Add_Tick(...)` and removed `$Form.Add_Closing({ $timer.Dispose() })`